# Rails f.submit tag disable_with isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, form-helpers

I'm trying to edit this `submit` tag to make it disable itself once I click it using the `disable_with` option, but it isn't generating the correct HTML.

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up", :disable_with => "Saving..." %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "links" %>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

As I said, it's not generating the correct html. It's just generating the same HTML it would without the submit tag. What's wrong here?

Edit: Here's the HTML it's generating:

```
<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign up" />
```

Edit 2: It seems like this is only not working for Devise forms....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. It seems to be some problem with Devise not using the views specified by `rails g devise:views`.